# How to find a nested control inside of asp repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find `<span id="source">` inside of my repeater the listControl is coming back null.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptRssFeed" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RssFeedItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="socialListItem" runat="server">
            <a href="<%# GetNavigationLink(Container.DataItem) %>" target="_blank" id="title" runat="server"><%# GetTitle(Container.DataItem) %></a>
            <span class="source" id="source" runat="server"><%# GetSource(Container.DataItem) %></span>
            <p><%# GetTeaser(Container.DataItem) %></p>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <li class="alt" id="socialListItem" runat="server">
            <a href="<%# GetNavigationLink(Container.DataItem) %>" target="_blank" id="title" runat="server"><%# GetTitle(Container.DataItem) %></a>
            <span class="source" id="source" runat="server"><%# GetSource(Container.DataItem) %></span>
            <p><%# GetTeaser(Container.DataItem) %></p>
        </li>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

public void RssFeedItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl listControl = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("socialListItem");
    if (!ShowSource)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl spanControl = (HtmlGenericControl)listControl.FindControl("source");
        spanControl.Visible = false;
    }
    listControl.Attributes["class"] += ((XmlFeedItem)e.Item.DataItem).XmlFeedType;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Errors? Exceptions? Something else?

Comment: @Brissles - Looks like a boolean property that is used to determine whether the `span` is to be visible or not.

Comment: Begs the question, why is there any need to use HtmlGenericControls when standard asp controls would be far cleaner and simpler.

Comment: You need to check if you are checking for the List Item, li, in the ListItemType.Item or AlternatingItem   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if you are checking for the List Item in the ListItemType.Item or AlternatingItem type.

```
public void RssFeedItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl listControl = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("socialListItem");

            if (listControl != null)
            {
                if (!ShowSource)
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl spanControl = (HtmlGenericControl)listControl.FindControl("source");
                    spanControl.Visible = false;
                }

                listControl.Attributes["class"] += ((XmlFeedItem)e.Item.DataItem).XmlFeedType;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an `HttpException` from `HtmlGenericControl listControl = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("socialListItem");` on InnerText - Cannot get inner content of socialListItem because the contents are not literal

Comment: sorry, what do you mean did I try InnerHtml?